# How to retrieve data from an external nested json file on seed.rb

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, seed

I want to retrieve data from an external nested JSON file on my `seed.rb`
The JSON looks like this:

`{"people":[{"name":"John", "age":"23"}, {"name":"Jack", "age":"25"}]}`

I saw a [solution on GitHub](https://github.com/liveinsights/clone-monthly-subscriptions/blob/master/db/seeds.rb) but it only works on non-nested JSON.

Comment: To access the items in that array you need to do `item["people"][0]["name"]` since the people's attribute is in an array

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have JSON file `db/seeds.json`:

```
{"people":[{"name":"John", "age":"23"}, {"name":"Jack", "age":"25"}]}
```

You can use it like this in your `db/seeds.rb`:

```
seeds = JSON.parse(Rails.root.join("db", "seeds.json"), symbolize_names: true)

User.create(seeds[:people])
```

`seeds[:people]` in this case is array of hashes with user attributes

Answer (score 0):

if you have:

```
json_data = {"people":[{"name":"John", "age":"23"}, {"name":"Jack", "age":"25"}]}
```

when you do:

```
json_data[:people]
```

you'll get an array:

```
[{:name=>"John", :age=>"23"}, {:name=>"Jack", :age=>"25"}]
```

if you want to use this array to populate a model, you can do:

```
People.create(json_data[:people])
```

if you want to read each item values, you can iterate through your data, like:

```
json_data[:people].each {|p| puts p[:name], p[:age]}
```